# statusbar storyboard not shown

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was wondering if this a bug(/feature) of Xcode 9.x or not. I noticed the status bar at the top isn't rendered by default in the storyboard. If i launch the app in the simulator/device i do get to see the status bar.

Anyone got an idea? thanks!

Storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3CZI.png

Simulator/Device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ICMm.png

Comment: This happens only if you drag a VC without a NavigationController embedded to it or if you have top bar set to None. Adding a NavigationController to VC will show Navigation bar with status bar

Comment: It's not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!