# Show status bar in storyboard inside xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am working on an existing xcode project that doesn't show the status bar within storyboard. If I run the simulator it does show, but I want to see the status bar inside storyboard also.

- I have searched my project for "status bar" and nothing was found.
- I have also looked inside my plist file and cannot find any options
  to enable this.
- I have started a new project, and the status bar shows fine. So I
  believe there is a setting somewhere in this project that disabled
  this.

Any idea how I can enable this?

There are already several old posts that ask this question, in which the answers do not work with the latest Xcode that I am using.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130743/how-to-show-status-bar-in-storyboard-of-xcode) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935868/status-bar-hidden-in-storyboard) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788017/statusbar-storyboard-not-shown).

[No status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9P40.png)

[What I want it to look like..with status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0rqd.png)

Comment: Xcode lets _you_ say what device type you want to see in the storyboard. So tell it that you want to see a device that has a "notch". By the way, the status bar is not the notch.

Comment: How do I do that? iPhone 11 is selected by the top where u choose what device you want for the simulator. I can't find any other phone options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to select the device with notch. Please follow steps in attached.

[image]